# Calling class methods and displaying results

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

UPDATED AS FIXES ARE POSTED

Issue I'm having now is getting the displayResults method to call in weight height and gender for the calculations. Also I have one other issue where I need the user inputs to ignore what case the response is in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myHealthCalculator 
{    
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    displayPurpose();

    //create person object
    myPerson person = new myPerson();       

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.print("Please enter weight in pounds: ");
    person.weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter height in inches: ");
    person.height = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter your age in years: ");
    person.age = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter your gender (M/F): ");
    person.gender = (char) keyboard.nextDouble();

    person.bodyMassIndex(0, 0);
    person.calorieComp(0, 0, 0);
displayResults(person.bodyMassIndex(0, 0),person.calorieComp(0, 0, 0));
}

public static void displayPurpose()
{
    System.out.println("This program implements a Health Assistance "
            + "Calculator");
    System.out.println("\nGiven a weight, height, and age, it will compute:");
    System.out.println("    BMI - Body Mass Index");
    System.out.println("    Calories needed per day to maintain weight");
    System.out.println();
}   

public static void displayResults(double resultBMI, int calCompu)
{
    Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner( System.in );
    final double LOW_N_BMI = 18.5;
    final double HI_N_BMI = 24.9;

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.printf("%nA BMI in the range of " + LOW_N_BMI + " to " 
            + HI_N_BMI + " is considered normal" );
    //getters here, gender, age, weight kgs and height meters.
    System.out.printf("Current weight in kgs is: " + "%.2f", weight);
    System.out.printf("Current height in meteres: " + "%.3f", height);
    if (gender == 'm')
        System.out.println("Gender is: " + "Male");
    else
        System.out.println("Gender is: " + "Female");

    System.out.printf("Your BMI is: " + "%.1f", resultBMI);
    if (resultBMI < LOW_N_BMI)
        System.out.println("BMI is below normal");
    else if (resultBMI > HI_N_BMI)
        System.out.println("BMI is above normal");
    else
        System.out.println("BMI is normal");

    System.out.printf("%nTo maintain your current weight, you should consume ", calCompu, "calories per day.");        

    if (resultBMI < LOW_N_BMI)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to try and reach the normal range? ");
        String questionOne = keyboard2.next();
        if (questionOne == "y")
        {
            System.out.println("how many pounds would you like to gain per week? ");
            double questionTwo = keyboard2.nextDouble();
            double gainRate = questionTwo * 3500;
            System.out.println(" To gain " + questionTwo + " pound(s) per "
                    + "week, you should consume " + gainRate + "Calories per day.");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if (resultBMI > HI_N_BMI)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to try and reach the normal range? ");
        double questionThree = keyboard2.nextDouble();
        double loseRate = questionThree / 3500;
        System.out.println(" To lose " + questionThree + " pound(s) per "
                    + "week, you should consume " + loseRate + "Calories per day.");
    }
    else
    {       
    }

}  
}
```

and the other class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myPerson 
{
// data fields
double weight = 0;
double height = 0;
int age = 0;
double gender = ' ';  //char 'M' or 'F'
private double resultBMI = 0;

//person constructor
public myPerson ()
{
    //conversion factors for metric (need to convert input 
    //which will be in imperial messurements)
    final double KG_WEIGHT_CONV = 2.2;   
    final double MT_HEIGHT_CONV = 0.0254;
    double calCopu = 0.0;
}

public void setWeight (double weight, double KG_WEIGHT_CONV) {
    this.weight = weight / KG_WEIGHT_CONV;     
}

public void setHeight (double height, double MT_HEIGHT_CONV) {
    this.height = height * MT_HEIGHT_CONV;     
}
public void setAge (int age) {
    this.age = age;     
}

public void setGender (double gender) {
    this.gender = gender;     
}    


public double getWeight () {
    return weight;     
}

public double getHeight () {
    return height;     
}


public int getAge () {
    return age;     
}

public double getGender () {
    return gender;     
}

//instance method to calculate BMI
public double bodyMassIndex(double weightKgs, double heightMeters)
{ 
    /**
     * Compute a person's BMI, will return a double value
     * squares the height using the pow method from java.Math.
    */
    return (weightKgs / Math.pow(heightMeters, 2));
}  

public int calorieComp(double weightInKg, double heightInMeters, int ageInYears)
{  
    double heightInCentimeters = heightInMeters * 100;

    System.out.println("Select your activity level: ");
    System.out.println("  1 - Sedentary");
    System.out.println("  2 - Moderately active (light exercise 1-3 days a week) ");
    System.out.println("  3 - Active (moderate exercise 3-5 days a week) ");
    System.out.println("  4 - Very active (heavy exercise 6-7 days a week) ");
    System.out.printf("Enter choice from above: ");

    char aFactor;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    aFactor = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    switch (aFactor)
    {
        case '1':
            aFactor = (char) 1.2;  //Sedentary people
            break; 
        case '2':
            aFactor = (char) 1.375;    //Moderate active people
            break;
        case '3':
            aFactor = (char) 1.55; //Active people
            break;
        case '4':
            aFactor = (char) 1.725;    //Very active people
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Invalid choice entered!");
    }

    if (gender == 'm')
    {

    //return men
    double basalMetabolicRate = 13.397 * weightInKg + 4.799 
            * heightInCentimeters - 5.677 * ageInYears + 88.362;

    double psyActFact = basalMetabolicRate * aFactor;
    int calCompu = (int) Math.ceil(psyActFact);

    return calCompu;
    }

    else
    {

    //return women
    double basalMetabolicRate = 9.247 * weightInKg + 3.098 
            * heightInCentimeters - 4.330 * ageInYears + 447.593;

    double psyActFact = basalMetabolicRate * aFactor;
    int calCompu = (int) Math.ceil(psyActFact);

    return calCompu;
    }      
}
}
```

Comment: "I seem to be having a bit of trouble" can you be more specific. Which line of code are you having trouble with and what error are you getting?

Comment: `person.gender = (char) keyboard.nextDouble();` looks suspicious to me...

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it? I've been stuck on this for a few days now...

Comment: Getting closer on getting the bugs worked on, much thanks to all those willing to provide assistance to new programmers on here =) Much love for all. My last issue is that my program is not moving the data around like it should be, I get **ZERO** returned on all outputs

Answer (score 0):

So I've figure it out a bit more and wanted to share, I changed the `displayResults` method to

```
displayResults(person, person.bodyMassIndex(0, 0),person.calorieComp(0, 0, 0));
```

and in the `main` method I changed the `displayResults` call to

```
displayResults(person, person.bodyMassIndex(0, 0),person.calorieComp(0, 0, 0));
```

Also I removed two lines of code from the `main` method that was causing the program to ask for the activity level twice.

This is now allowing data to move and I'm getting some results returned.
However it is giving the result of **NaNBMI** for "Your BMI is: " Also still need to get it to convert it to meters and kgs... However progress was made, I'll post as I go if I make any more headway, any more suggestions are welcomed =D